# What should I do if exposing ports in a Dockerfile do not take effect?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I have the following Dockerfile to run an Nginx server but I can't seem to get Docker to expose port 80 thru my host machine so I can access it externally:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest
EXPOSE 80
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get -y install apt-utils
RUN apt-get -y dist-upgrade
RUN apt-get -y install nginx 
CMD service nginx start
```

If I run the following command after building the image, **`docker run -p 80:80 -d nginxserver`**, I can get the correct global settings to take effect, however my newly created Docker container does not run persistently and it exits after a brief second.

If I try **`docker run -it /bin/bash -d nignxserver`**, this will allow my Docker container to work, however I won't be able to connect to the Nginx server outside the host machine.

If I try **`docker run -p 80:80 -it /bin/bash -d nignxserver`**, this will fail with the following error message:

> docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed:
>   container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec:
>   \"-it\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.

What would be the correct solution here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution is just to use the [standard nginx image](https://hub.docker.com/_/nginx/), if you're not really going to customize the image at all.

If you're writing a custom image, you should broadly assume commands like `service` just don't work.  The CMD of the image you show (assuming it's successful) attempts to launch nginx as a background service; once it's started in the background, the container's main process has finished and the container exits.  The CMD generally needs to launch the single process that the container runs *in the foreground*.

In terms of your various `docker run` gyrations, the options always come in the same order:

```sh
docker run \
  -d -p 80:80 \           # docker-specific options
  nginxserver \           # the image name
  nginx -g 'daemon off;'  # the command to run and its options
```

If you specify an alternate command (like `/bin/bash`) that runs *instead of* the main container process, and if the container normally would have run a network server, you get the shell instead.  `/bin/bash` is a command and not an argument to `-it`; the same breakdown would be

```sh
docker run \
  --rm -i -t \            # docker-specific options
  nginxserver \           # the image name
  /bin/bash               # the command to run and its options
```

Comment: The CMD command worked and the docker run also did. I'm not sure why the `-d` parameter needs to be specified by itself before the port args, but it worked in the end. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to run with `--privileged` to listen on ports under 1024.

Also, `service nginx start` exist immediately (This is covered by David Maze)

You should instead use `CMD nginx`

Comment: You don't need to be `--privileged` to listen on a "low" port from inside a container, you just need to have user ID 0.  (Just like ordinary Linux.)